# Where does android app chooses which drawable folder to use

Tags: android, android-layout, mdpi

Both my device and Google nexus have 320 dpi display, but when I am building the same source code(VideoEditor app), for Nexus, it chooses icons from xhdpi folder while when I build it for my device, it chooses mdpi folder.

Can anyone tell why is this happening?
Where exactly in the source code it takes this decision of icon set selection?

Also, when an app gets built for a particular device, what all configuration files it uses? 
bcoz same source code is giving different results when built for both devices (although having same dpi)

Answer (score 0):

Each handset picks the resources it needs from the drawable folder associated with it's hardware specification.

If your device chooses m-dpi then the manufacturers of your device have decided that m-dpi is best for that phone.

The source code that chooses this is not part of your application, the Android system itself does this automatically at runtime and us developers have no control over it.

Comment: Close enough. Actually not that because manufacturer decided so, but because of resolution of display.

Comment: I considered writing that, but he said that both screens had the same resolution - but the manufacturer could have configured it that the device used m-dpi. Stranger things have happened...